# For loop in django templates using Integerfield in model object

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have a model like this:

```
class Testimonial(models.Model):
    rating = models.IntegerField(_("Rating"))
```

I'm looping over all testimonials in Django templates using one for loop, now how do I display the ratings for each testimonial object.

My stars class in HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the pastebin for the entire loop's HTML.
[For loop HTML in my Django Templates](https://pastebin.com/mqvQtBgd)

This is part of my views.py:

```
    # Testimonials section
    testimonials = Testimonial.objects.all()
    if testimonials:
        context['testimonials'] = testimonials
```

This is the code for for loop which I currently have:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
                            {% for item in testimonials  %}
                                <div class="testi-box">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <div class="client-drow mt-30 p-3 pt-0">
                                            <img src={{item.image.url}} alt="" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail testi-img rounded-circle">
                                            <div class="testi-content mt-2">
                                                <div class="client-name">
                                                    <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
                                                    <p class="mb-0">{{item.designation}}</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <p class="user-review text-center text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-format-quote-open"></i>{{item.description}}</p>
                                                <div class="review-star">
                                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
                                                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
                                                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
                                                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
                                                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Can we see the loop?

Comment: I have added it to the question.
still here it is https://pastebin.com/mqvQtBgd

Comment: Add code itself instead of links to/screenshots of it.

Comment: Am I correct that your question is how to generate as many `li ... class star` as need for particular `rating` value? Also please elaborate how should `star-half` appear if `rating` is `IntegerField`.

Comment: Yes that's correct, is there a way to tackle the half star if we use the decimal field?

Comment: I have tried converting this to a decimal field and use floor division in django templates with if blocks, but no luck. I was not able to take floor of the variable.